# Nesting ResourceDictionaries with MergedDictionaries in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to split up a `ResourceDictionary` containing styles for multiple controls in our current UWP application. The file has grown to about 3000 lines and has become a living hell to manage, so I decided to split it up into smaller, more specific `ResourceDictionaries` and include them using `MergedDictionaries`.

`App.xaml`

```
<common:BootStrapper x:Class="Asteria.Ion.App"
                     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                     xmlns:common="using:Template10.Common"
                     xmlns:styles="using:Asteria.Ion.Styles"
                     RequestedTheme="Dark">

    <common:BootStrapper.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\Custom.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\CustomControls.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </common:BootStrapper.Resources>
</common:BootStrapper>
```

`CustomControls.xaml` contains references to other `ResourceDictionaries`.

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="using:Template10.Controls"
    xmlns:behaviors="using:Template10.Behaviors"
    xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
    xmlns:local="using:Asteria.Ion.Styles">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Shared.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Templates.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ComponentBlock.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="FlowAgent.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Planning.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ProjectDialog.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Inspector.xaml" /-->
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

This will always produce the following exception:
`Failed to assign to property 'Windows.UI.Xaml.ResourceDictionary.Source' because the type 'Windows.Foundation.String' cannot be assigned to the type 'Windows.Foundation.Uri'. [Line: 12 Position: 37]`

I've tried changing the source URI numerous times, but it keeps giving this error. Only commenting out all the `ResourceDictionary` elements in `CustomControls.xaml` helps. But then I get exceptions concerning missing styles of course.

Some URI formats I've tried:

- `/Styles/Shared.xaml`
- `Styles/Shared.xaml`
- `Styles\Shared.xaml`
- `.\Shared.xaml`
- `ms-appx:///Styles/Shared.xaml`

None of them work.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not trying to reference styles in an external assembly though.

Comment: I see. Maybe you should try this syntax anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end it had nothing to do with the URI structure, but with a combination of `ThemeDictionaries` and `MergedDictionaries`.

What was working before:

In `App.Resources`:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/Themes.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/CustomControls.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Where `Themes.xaml` contained `ThemeDictionaries` and `CustomControls.xaml` contained `<Styles>` ( a lot of them ).

After splitting `CustomControls.xaml`, it no longer contained any styles, but only `MergedDictionaries`. 
Looking something like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="ControlStyles/ProjectDialog.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="ControlStyles/Inspector.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

`Inspector.xaml` contained a `Style` using `{ThemeResource}` and it appears that's where it went wrong. The solution/work-around in the end was to include a `MergedDictionaries` with a references to `Themes.xaml` in `Inspector.xaml`.

Now if anyone can explain the exact reasoning behind this solution, I'd be much obliged.

Answer (score 2):

From the error message,XAML Compiler failed to translate the Source Property of nested ResourceDictionaries. The easiest and fastest workaround is to add the nested ResourceDictionaries in `App.Xaml.cs`:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
   ...
    var applicationMergedDics = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries;
    applicationMergedDics[0].MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Styles/Shared.xaml") });
    applicationMergedDics[0].MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Styles/Templates.xaml") });
    ...
    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
}
```

Notes: Don't forget to remove the `MergedDictionaries` in `CustomControls.xaml`. And the error will be gone.

Comment: This solved my problem, however it created another. If the app is launched from PowerShell using `start-process` then the dictionaries aren't loaded and styles aren't applied. Not sure if running it in this way means OnLaunched isn't hit but if anyone has any ideas that would be great. For now had to solve my problem by including a ref to the mergedDictionary in each style - not ideal. Thanks

Comment: Start UWP through powershell will trigger `OnActivated` lifecycle method, you can put the codes in a normal function name it like `Myfunc`, and call `Myfunc` both in `OnLaunched` and `OnActivated`.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing - full answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59138929/uwp-mergeddictionary-style-that-references-other-style-throws-error