# UWP MergedDictionary Style that references other style throws error

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Having real problems creating a Merged Dictionary of styles that need to use values from another `MergedDictionary` (`Brushes.xaml`).

When I try and reference it from another file I get the following error:

`"Failed to assign to property 'Windows.UI.Xaml.ResourceDictionary.Source' because the type 'Windows.Foundation.String' cannot be assigned to the type 'Windows.Foundation.Uri'. [Line: x Position: y]"`

> E.g. in a Resource Dictionary I have the following that works..

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Brushes.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource customBrush1}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource customBrush2}" />
```

However, this isn't ideal as I'd need to reference `Brushes.xaml` in every style resource dictionary. So what I want to do is declare the `Brushes.xaml` in `App.xaml` but everything I try results in the error above. It basically does not recognise the resources defined in `Brushes.xaml` unless I add them to each individual style.

> E.g. What I want (to be able to do in App.xaml)...

```
<Application x:Class="Test.UWP.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             RequestedTheme="Light">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Test.Xamarin.Forms.Themes.UWP/Brushes.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Test.Xamarin.Forms.Themes.UWP/CustomStyles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

`CustomStyles.xaml` contains

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\Button\BackButton.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\Button\Default.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\Button\HyperlinkBasicButton.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\Button\HyperlinkButton.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And e.g. `Styles\Button\Default.xaml` contains..

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CustomBrush1}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource CustomBrush2}" />
```

Where CustomBrush1 is defined in `Brushes.xaml`.

I've tried so many things e.g. Tried adding Brushes.xaml to the CustomStyles.xaml - doesn't work. Tried changing the order as [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references) states they should be in inverse order - this doesn't work.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks

As per comment, here is the `Brushes.xaml`

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomBrush1"
                     Color="Black}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomBrush2"
                     Color="White}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: I think this is not the problem of merging dictionary! one of your `<x:String ...></x:String>` must change to `<x:Uri></x:Uri>`

Comment: I don't understand - which string? Thanks

Comment: Can you upload your **Brushes.xaml** and **CustomStyles.xaml** files anywhere which I can download and see them?

Comment: `CustomStyles.xaml` is in the original post and I've just added `Brushes.xaml`

Answer (score 0):

From your description, this behavior is by-design, derive this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references#lookup-behavior-for-xaml-resource-references) we could find.

> The lookup sequence then checks the next parent object in the runtime object tree of the app....

If you place `Brushes.xaml` at patent level, the sub level `Default.xaml` can not get the brush resource and throw exception. The best practice is refer `Brushes.xaml` in each resource like the first scenario mentioned above.

And if `Brushes.xaml` and `Default.xaml` are not in the same folder , we need use `ms-appx://` scheme to refer it .

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestApp.Styles.Button"
    >
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Brushes.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CustomBrush1}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource CustomBrush2}" />
    </Style>  
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then add above to `CustomStyles`.

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestApp"
    >
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/Button/Default.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

At last, we just need to add CustomStyles into `MergedDictionaries` within **App.xaml** file

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="CustomStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I have done, kind of. But it means that in every style referenced in `CustomStyles.xaml` I will need a reference to `Brushes.xaml`. That isn't ideal, it also exhibits unpredictable behaviour that I won't go into now. But anyway I've found a solution which I'll post next. Also as I understand it using `ms-appx:///` is only required if the file is in a different assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem. The problem being that one resource dictionary cannot reference anything in another if they are both declared in `App.Xaml` *(unless the value is in the ControlTemplate - see below)*

The solution I have found is to remove all resource dictionaries from App.Xaml, so App.Xaml basically looks like this:

```
<Application x:Class="Dwp.CRMobile.UWP.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             RequestedTheme="Light">
</Application>
```

And then instead add them to the `OnLaunched` method of `App.Xaml.cs` as below. Note you will also need to add this to `OnActivated` if the app could also be run by PowerShell etc.

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    var eventArgs = e as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;
    var data = new ActivationArgs(e.Kind, eventArgs.Uri.Query);

    AddResources();

    Run(e, data);
}

protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
#if RELEASE
    var data = new ActivationArgs(e.Kind, e.Arguments);
#else
    var data = new ActivationArgs(ActivationKind.Protocol, e.Arguments);
#endif

    AddResources();

    Run(e, data);
}

private static void AddResources()
{
    var applicationMergedDictionaries = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries;
    applicationMergedDictionaries.Add(GetResourceDictionary("ms-appx:///Test.Xamarin.Forms.Themes.UWP/Brushes.xaml"));
    applicationMergedDictionaries.Add(GetResourceDictionary("ms-appx:///Test.Xamarin.Forms.Themes.UWP/CustomStyles.xaml"));
    applicationMergedDictionaries.Add(GetResourceDictionary("ms-appx:///Test.HTMobile.Core.UWP/Styles.xaml"));
    applicationMergedDictionaries.Add(GetResourceDictionary("ms-appx:///Test.CRFramework.Xamarin.Forms.UWP/Root.xaml"));
}
```

It's an odd one - something to do with when resources are loaded. Because if I stick to the original method in `App.xaml` and use a value from `Brushes.xaml` in a style defined in `CustomStyles.xaml` it **will work** if the value is set in a `ControlTemplate`, but it will not if it is in a standard Setter Property. This method above solved this problem for me, so hopefully it will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this sort of behaviour is by design, you should not be trying to reference external resource dictionaries (styles or themes) directly as this creates a tightly coupled relationship between the two files, so much so that you might as well just make them the one file.

To avoid this, in the header of `CustomStyles.xaml` create *stub* definitions for the resources that you need to reference, this serves a number of purposes:

1. You have documented the resources that your resource dictionary is dependent upon
2. You can declare the default definition of the required resource, further documenting your *custom styles* but also making sure that your resources will function, even if the consumer has not referenced the external resources (`Brushes.xaml`)

   - Which by the way it the reason for the error in the first place.
   - You do not have to include the real definition, but as best practise you really should. If the `Brushes.xaml` will be included all the time anyway, then your stubs *should* be overridden each time, but because we cannot control how or if *Brushes.xaml*
     is defined, it is A good idea to include the real and complete definition of the needed resources.

So yes, you could be lazy and insert the entire `Brushes.xaml` directly into your `CustomStyles.xaml` however you should only insert the resources that `CustomStyles.xaml` actually needs

> This is the standard method for overriding standard UWP control templates, after a few times and it becomes second nature, Visual studio even does this for you if you right click a control in the designer and choose *Edit Template* then *Edit a Copy...*
>   [image: Edit Control Template from VS]
>   It will inject all the definitions for resources that are referenced by the selected control, but are not defined in the global generic UWP resources.

Finally, when you reference `CustomStyles.xaml` in your merged dictionary, include the reference to `Brushes.xaml` *AFTER* it, this will make `Brusjes.xaml` overwrite the *stub* definitions that you included in `CustomStyles.xaml`.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="CustomStyles.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Brushes.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```